# UndefVarError error inside ```@time``` scope

Tags: julia

I have the following piece of code:

```
@time begin

    results = nothing

    for i in 1:3

        if results == nothing
            results = DataFrame(A=1, B=2)
        else
            results = vcat(results, DataFrame(A=1, B=2))
        end
    end

end
```

Without the `@time begin/end` part the code runs fine.

However, inside the `@time begin/end` part, I get `UndefVarError: results not defined`.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Are you using a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes I am.......

Comment: This is a bug in SoftGlobalScope.jl.  Report it here: https://github.com/stevengj/SoftGlobalScope.jl/issues/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have a scoping error. Your assignment of `results` occurs in a scope that the rest of the block is not accessing. You can fix this by specifying that you are making the assignment in your local scope:

```
@time begin

    local results = nothing

    for i in 1:3

        if results == nothing
            results = DataFrame(A=1, B=2)
        else
            results = vcat(results, DataFrame(A=1, B=2))
        end
    end

end
```

Note that you would get the same error with just the `begin ... end` block, without `@time`.